# How can I prevent Ubuntu 22.04 from logging every line of output from a podman-based systemd service twice?

Tags: ubuntu, podman, systemd

I have podman-based containerized systemd services running on Ubuntu 22.04. Every line of output is sent to `journald` twice: once by `conmon` and once by `podman`.

As an example, here's my `/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=MongoDB container

[Service]
Restart=always
ExecStart=/usr/bin/podman start -a mongodb
ExecStop=/usr/bin/podman stop -t 10 mongodb

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have a similar file for a container running my own Node.js application, and exactly the same thing happens, so it's nothing to do with the applications inside the containers.

I don't see non-podman-based systemd services doing this at all.

I know the duplication comes from `podman` and `conmon` due to lines like this:

```
Dec 11 08:59:24 52.1.177.253.worker.holon-mirror.apos.dev conmon[4959]: {"t":...}
Dec 11 08:59:24 52.1.177.253.worker.holon-mirror.apos.dev podman[4768]: {"t":...}
```

Details of the output omitted, but yes 100% identical each time.

I could use grep to filter out either `conmon` or `podman`, however I also need to be able to tell the systemd units (services) apart. So in practice I prefer to use:

```
journalctl --output with-unit
```

Which gives me:

```
Mon 2023-12-11 08:59:24 UTC 52.1.177.253.worker.holon-mirror.apos.dev mongodb.service[4959]: {"t":...}
Mon 2023-12-11 08:59:24 UTC 52.1.177.253.worker.holon-mirror.apos.dev mongodb.service[4768]: {"t":...}
```

Now I can tell which lines come from the `mongodb` service, and not the other one... but, I can't tell `podman` from `conmon`.

I've determined that I can use `--output json` to get access to everything at once. From there, I could manually look for `"SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER":"podman"` and `"_SYSTEMD_UNIT":"mongodb.service"`, which is enough information for me to solve this problem the hard way.

But before I commit to that, I'd like to know if there's a way to just get podman to only log in one of these two ways in the first place.

Comment: What about `journalctl -u mongodb.service`?

Comment: `journalctl -u mongodb.service` restricts to that service, but still shows everything twice, under the two different syslog identifiers.

Comment: I wound up using the JSON format and narrowing that down to a less verbose JSON format for long term storage and analysis. I do the filtering-out of podman (had to pick one) at that stage. I also wound up writing tools that can output that directly or reconstruct classic syslog format.